# Swift 2.2 - Navigation controller's toolbar: when is it added to a view controller and view frame size updated?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uitoolbar

I have got into a case that stuck me nearly a day.

I got this ViewController:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(“view0: \(view.frame)”)

        // initialize items...
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
        navigationController?.toolbar.items = items

        print(“view1: \(view.frame)”)
    }
}
```

At the first time running, the console displays as expected:

```
view0: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
view1: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 423.0)
```

After I refresh it by pressing a button, the console displays:

```
view0: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
view1: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0) // why not 423.0??
```

`MyViewController` is actually a part of `UIPageViewController`. So after I come back to this unexpected-height-value (`568.0` vs `423.0`) view controller from other view controllers, the display is as expected (`423.0`).

Why is the height value not updated for the first time refresh and updated correctly after I come back from other view controllers?
Can you help me propose a solution to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just got a solution: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` does help!

In `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, view frame size is stable, so UI can be updated safely inside.

Regards